# How to properly route a component that renders a list based on the /:elementId/ in the URL

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-redux, react-router

I am basically making a discord clone using rails, react-router, react-redux, JavaScript and PostgreSQL.  My servers and channels all render but I want to only render the channels when a server is clicked by routing each server's channels to #/servers/:serverId/channels.  My link to the url works fine but something about the route (i think) gives me a 500 internal server error: http://localhost:3000/api/servers/NaN/channels

I have already tried messing with my store using an activeChannel: true/false but that seemed to make things more complicated because it meant mutating my store.

server_index_item.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link, Route, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
///
import ChannelIndexContainer from '../channels/channel_index_container';
import ChannelIndex from '../channels/channel_index';

class ServerIndexItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { server, serverId, channelIds, activeChannels } = this.props;


    return (
      <div>

        <li className="server-index-item">
          <NavLink to={`/servers/${server.id}/channels`}>
            <span>{server.id}</span>
            <img className="discord-server-icon"
              src={server.image_url}
              alt={server.title} />
          </NavLink>

          <Route path="/servers/:serverId/channels"
            render={(props) => <ChannelIndexContainer {...props} serverId={serverId} channelIds={channelIds} activeChannels={activeChannels} />}></Route>
          </li>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Channel_Index.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import ChannelIndexContainer from './channel_index_container';
import ChannelShow from './channel_show';

//
import TestRoute from '../test_components/test_route';

class ChannelIndex extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestServerChannels(this.props.serverId);
  }


  render() {
    const { channels, serverId, channelIds, activeChannels } = this.props;

    const channelFilter = channels.filter(channel => {
      return channel.server_id === serverId;
    });


    return(
      <div>
        <ul>
          {channelFilter.map(channel =>
            <ChannelShow
              key={channel.id}
              channel={channel}
              activeChannels={activeChannels}
              serverId={serverId} />)}

        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and my channels controller

```
class Api::ChannelsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @channels = Channel.where("server_id = ?", params[:server_id])
  end


  def show
    @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

I when I click on a server it goes to the /servers/:serverId/channels which is how I have it nested in my routes, but it still renders every channel instead of just the channels for the clicked server, then throws a: GET http://localhost:3000/api/servers/NaN/channels 500 (Internal Server Error).  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I ended up mutating part of my state to solve this and it actually worked out very well.  First I made these action creators:

```
export const TOGGLE_SERVER = "TOGGLE_SERVER";
export const UNTOGGLE_SERVER ="UNTOGGLE_SERVER";


export const toggleServer = (server_id) => ({
  type: TOGGLE_SERVER,
  server_id
});

export const unToggleServer = () => ({
  type: UNTOGGLE_SERVER,
});
```

Then I made a new reducer for my store that would be nested in entities(along with servers, channels, users etc.)

```
import {
  TOGGLE_SERVER,
  UNTOGGLE_SERVER
} from '../actions/toggle_actions';

import merge from 'lodash/merge';

const toggleReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TOGGLE_SERVER:
      const toggledServer = { ["serverId"]: action.server_id};
      return merge({}, state, toggledServer);
    case UNTOGGLE_SERVER:
      const nextState = merge({}, state);
      delete nextState["serverId"];
      return nextState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export default toggleReducer;
```

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  toggleServer: (server_id) => dispatch(toggleServer(server_id)),
  unToggleServer: () => dispatch(unToggleServer()),
});
```

then in server_index_item.jsx:

```
class ServerIndexItem extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

    handleClick(server_id) {
      this.props.unToggleServer();
      this.props.toggleServer(server_id);
    }


  render() {
    const { server, serverId, channelIds } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>

        <li className="server-index-item">
          <NavLink to={`/servers/${server.id}/channels`}>
            <span>{server.id}</span>
            <img className="discord-server-icon"
              src={server.image_url}
              alt={server.title} />
          </NavLink>
                       // here its a button for now
          <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(server.id)}>toggleTest</button>
          <ChannelIndexContainer serverId={serverId} channelIds={channelIds} />
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default ServerIndexItem;
```

And finally in my ChannelIndex I checked if the channel.server_id === activeServerId and to render the channels if true.  My first slack post so I am a little unsure if my original problem was not elaborated on properly so I hope my answer to my own question(with a different solution) makes up for it.